# Can't add loopcuts to certain faces

Tags: loop, looping

I can't add loop cuts to these faces of my model:
[image: Can't add loop cuts]

I know it may be an ngon therefore I tried to fill those holes but the loop cut still doesnt work. I've tried separate the selection from the mesh and bridge the edges but it just made it worse. What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this issue? Thank You for the answers in advance. Download link to my file: [image]

Comment: You want to join the slots from left to right?

Comment: No. I wanted to make a lattice panel to the left face like in this picture: https://ibb.co/nCtKXTC  Sorry if my question was not clear. English is not my first language.

Comment: Why don't you add this panel instead of cutting the existing wall? As your model is, the holes (as they are in your file) correspond to inner elements.No real wall is built like that.

Comment: You are right. This solution is the best in this case. I tried your suggestion. I've selected the edges of the left face, and duplicated it, then separated by selection. Pressed F to fill the edges and extruded it a little bit. The edge loops still didn't work, but it worked after I dissolved the edges from the extruded side. Thanks for your suggestion! I know the insides of my building is very glitchy hehe... I am learning from my mistakes.

Comment: Loop cuts will work only with quad. You've to make your panel from a quad.